# Adding constraints to UITableViewCell contentView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to add constraints to tableViewCellSubViews, like so -

```
import UIKit

class SnakeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var lessonViews = Array<UIView>()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        for var i = 0; i < 3; ++i
        {
            var view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(i) * 110.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0))
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
            self.contentView.addSubview(view)
            lessonViews.append(view)
        }

        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsForEvenDistributionOfViews(lessonViews, relativeToCenterOfView: self, vertically: false))

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

And the constraints code -

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {

    class func constraintsForEvenDistributionOfViews(views:Array<UIView>,relativeToCenterOfView toView:UIView, vertically:Bool ) -> Array<NSLayoutConstraint> {
        var constraints = Array<NSLayoutConstraint>()
        let attribute = vertically ? NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY : NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX


        for (index, view) in enumerate(views) {

            let multiplier = CGFloat(2*index + 2) / CGFloat(views.count + 1)
            let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: attribute, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem:toView, attribute: attribute, multiplier: multiplier, constant: 0)
            constraints.append(constraint)
        }
        return constraints
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I add the constraints, all the subviews disappears.

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by adding these constraints?

Comment: spread the views horizontally in the cell

Comment: Does the views must have equal widths?

Comment: Yes, why do you ask ?

Comment: I have two questions: where do you use attribute2? And is that a typo: let multiplier = CGFloat(2*index + 2) / (CGFloat)(views.count + 1), the paranthesis around CGFloat.

Comment: @shannoga well I think the multiplier can be anything if the constant is zero, the result will be zero as well.

Answer (score 0):

The multiplier generally is 1.  The constant is the variable (horizontal or vertical amount.

You can setup your custom cell, its evenly distributed subViews, and its constraints, all within Storyboard.  It's much simpler to do it in Interface Builder, than creating and constraining views in code.

You simply dequeue a reusable cell, and it's already got its properly spaced views, because the cell instantiated and spaced them for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add constraints to the `contentView` of a `UITableViewCell` in `init(style:, reuseIdentifier:)` as follows (in this case adjusting with an inset of 5pt):

```
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
```

It works, but... the system will complain:

```
Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of the contentView of a UITableViewCell
is not supported and will result in undefined behavior
```

The warning appears only one time (even though I have multiple cells)

I am doing this to add an inner border and a shadow (without using additional views that will affect the smooth scroll). But the 'not supported' and 'undefined behavior' are things you may consider if you want to use this in a production environment.[image]